# If $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$, then $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, independence

I have two questions concerning Independence between random variables and vectors. Let $X,Y,Z,U:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be random variables.

1. If $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$, is $X$ independent of $(Y,Z)$?
2. If $X$ and $U$ are independent of $Y$ and $Z$, is $(X,U)$ independent of $(Y,Z)$?

MOTIVATION: I know that, if $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, then $X$ is independent to both $Y$ and $Z$ (because the real maps $(y,z)\mapsto y$ and $(y,z)\mapsto z$ are measurable). I would like to know if the converse holds, and if not, under which conditions it does (for instance, if the random variables have a certain distribution).

I do know that, for 1., if $Y$ and $Z$ are also independent, then $X$ is indeed independent of $(Y,Z)$.

Comment: What thoughts do you have on the matter?

Comment: What mean $(Y,Z)$?

Comment: @Masacroso $(Y,Z):\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a random vector.

Comment: @user355857 then you want to know if $(X,X)$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, right?

Comment: @Masacroso: do you mean that for independence random variables must have the same ranges?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I added more information.

Comment: @Ilya I would like to know if $\sigma(X)$ is independent of $\sigma(Y,Z)$, where $\sigma$ represents the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable / vector.

Comment: For independence it is sufficient to check independence of $\pi$-systems. You know a $\pi$-system that generates $\sigma((Y,Z))$?

Comment: @Calculon Do you mean $$\{(Y,Z)^{-1}(B_1\times B_2)=Y^{-1}(B_1)\cap Z^{-1}(B_2):\,B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\,?$$

Comment: @Calculon Then one needs to prove $$P(X\in B_1,Y\in B_2,Z\in B_3)=P(X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2,Z\in B_3),\, B_i\in\mathcal{B}.$$ How can be proved that?

Comment: Please be more precise about what you mean by "$X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$".

Comment: Possibly the simplest example destroying any hope that 1. or 2. could hold is when $(Y,Z)$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$ and $X=YZ$. Then $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are symmetric Bernoulli random variables, any two of them are independent but, for example, $X$ is not independent of $(Y,Z)$.

Comment: @user355857 I misunderstood your problem statement. I read it as $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ being independent whereas you probably meant $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ and $Z$ are independent. My comment pertains to the former interpretation. Did already gave a counterexample for the latter interpretation. I hope it is all clear now.