# Prove that a process has independent increments.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

I am considering a stochastic process $(X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$. I know that having independent increments means that for $t_1<t_2<\ldots < t_n$ I have that $X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}, X_{t_3}-X_{t_2},...$ are independent.

Now in my case I know that $\forall t, h$ we have $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $(X_s :s\le t)$. And I have to show that we have independent increments. But [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2946836/340973) suggests I cannot say that since $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $X_{s_1}$ and $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $X_{s_2}$ than $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $X_{s_2}-X_{s_1}$ so I am not sure how to conclude that I have independent increments.

Comment: In your case, $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $(X_{s_1},X_{s_2})$.

Comment: Yes, I was reading [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963756/if-x-is-independent-of-y-and-z-then-x-is-independent-of-y-z), but why does this help us?

Comment: Then $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $f(X_{s_1},X_{s_2})$ for any mble function $f$, e.g., $f(x,y)=x-y$.

Comment: But what is the argument you use to say $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is independent of $(X_{s_1},X_{s_2})$?

Comment: You said that: $X_{t-h}-X_t$ is independent of $(X_s:s\le t)$.

Comment: Oh. But if I would have said "$X_{t+h}-X_t$  is independent of $X_s \forall s\le t$". Then the result would not follow?

Comment: Oh, right, I just found the definition [independence for stochastic processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_one_stochastic_process)